# Implement Java interface (bridged through Delphi) in C++

Tags: java, android, delphi, c++builder

I would like to implement a Java interface (bridged through Delphi with Java2OP) and override its method in C++.

This was previously successfully done in my project with another Java SDK with the way shown below that I replicated (2 lasts blocks of code).

This compiles right but I get a `EJNI error` at run-time : `"onScanComplete method not found"`.

One other problem is if I try to instantiate the `TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback` class and give it to `TJBarcode2DWithSoft->setScanCallback(_di_JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback)`, I will always get the error :

```
ScanManager.cpp(147): no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'Mca::Dev::Api::TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback' to '_di_JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback' (aka 'DelphiInterface<Mca::Dev::Api::JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback>')
  systobj.h(261): candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Mca::Dev::Api::TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback' to 'const DelphiInterface<Mca::Dev::Api::JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback>' for 1st argument
  systobj.h(268): candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Mca::Dev::Api::TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback' to 'Mca::Dev::Api::JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback *' for 1st argument
  systobj.h(254): candidate template ignored: could not match 'DelphiInterface<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'Mca::Dev::Api::TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback'
  systobj.h(278): candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with TArg = Mca::Dev::Api::TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback &]
  systobj.h(248): candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

I wonder if I could do all of this with a local class in C++ as in Java without passing by Delphi.

**ScanCallBack Definition in SDK :**

```
public class Barcode2DWithSoft {
    ...
    public interface ScanCallback {
            void onScanComplete(int var1, int var2, byte[] var3);
    }
}
```

**Java project way to override ScanCallback interface method (no error):**

```
public Barcode2DWithSoft.ScanCallback  ScanBack= new Barcode2DWithSoft.ScanCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onScanComplete(int i, int length, byte[] bytes) {
              //Code Executed on Event
        }
    };

private void ScanBarcode(){
    barcode2DWithSoft.scan();
    barcode2DWithSoft.setScanCallback(ScanBack);
}
```

**Used way to do it in Delphi : ScanCallBack.pas**

```
type
  TNotifyScanCompleteEvent = procedure(P1: Integer; P2: Integer; P3: TJavaArray<Byte>) of object;

  TAJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback = class(TJavaLocal, JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback)
   FOnScanComplet : TNotifyScanCompleteEvent;
  public
    procedure onScanComplete(P1: Integer; P2: Integer; P3: TJavaArray<Byte>); virtual; cdecl;
    property OnScanComplet: TNotifyScanCompleteEvent read FOnScanComplet write FOnScanComplet;
  end;

implementation
{ TAJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback }

procedure TAJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback.onScanComplete(P1: Integer; P2: Integer; P3: TJavaArray<Byte>);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnScanComplet) then FOnScanComplet(P1,P2,P3);
end;
```

**When used in my C++ project**

```
TAJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback * ScanListener = new TAJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback();
ScanListener->OnScanComplet = mca5OnScanCallBack;
this->ScanMCA5->setScanCallback(_di_JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback(*ScanListener));
```

EDIT :

**Auto generated definition of JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback (bridge of Barcode2DWithSoft.ScanCallBack) by Java2OP :**

```
  JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallbackClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{CC4376C0-AB56-4CE0-9612-C947DAE2160F}']
   {class} procedure onScanComplete(P1: Integer; P2: Integer; P3: TJavaArray<Byte>); cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/zebra/adc/decoder/Barcode2DWithSoft$ScanCallback')]
  JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{202711EC-3B53-469F-B6CD-C8428226565D}']
  end;
  TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback = class(TJavaGenericImport<JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallbackClass, JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback>) end;
```

Comment: One of the considered functions mentions `const` - I wonder if that's the problem? No tsure thouhg...

Comment: This can be done without a Delphi bridge

Comment: You haven't included the code for the definition of JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback

Comment: @DaveNottage okay I added it in the EDIT. Idk if it can help since it's just the auto generated bridge of the Java Interface.

Answer (score 0):

The definition for JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback was autogenerated incorrectly. It should look like this:

```
  JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallbackClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{CC4376C0-AB56-4CE0-9612-C947DAE2160F}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/zebra/adc/decoder/Barcode2DWithSoft$ScanCallback')]
  JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{202711EC-3B53-469F-B6CD-C8428226565D}']
    procedure onScanComplete(P1: Integer; P2: Integer; P3: TJavaArray<Byte>); cdecl;
  end;

  TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback = class(TJavaGenericImport<JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallbackClass, JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback>) end;
```

Comment: Yes I saw that and found this strange too. I changed it but I still get the `EJNI error` at run-time : `"can't find onScanComplete method"`.
I don't understand why I can't cast `TJBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback` to `_di_JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback` though it implements the `JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback` interface. I wouldn't need to create such class in Delphi myself if I could use it , change it's `onScanComplete()` method and give it to `setScan()` that needs a `_di_JBarcode2DWithSoft_ScanCallback`.

Comment: Providing a callstack might help

Comment: The err is thrown in `dispatchToNative()` in `Androidapi.JNIBridge.pas` at line 651 : `" raise EJNIFatal.CreateResFmt(@SJNIMethodNotFound, 'onScanComplete'); "`It is called by lines like these in the class Barcode2DWithSoft, executed in another thread : 
`case 2:
                        if(Barcode2DWithSoft.this.scanCallback != null) {
                            temp = new byte[1];
              Barcode2DWithSoft.this.scanCallback.onScanComplete(-1, msg.arg1, temp);
                        }` 
So the `ScanCallBack` instance I gave it would not contain the onScanComplete method.

Comment: Though the `Barcode2DWithSoft.setScanCallback()` method do receive a `ScanCallback` instance `public synchronized void setScanCallback(final Barcode2DWithSoft.ScanCallback sc) {}`

Comment: I mean a complete callstack, not the last line. Also, the code in your 2nd last comment for case 2: appears to be attempting to call the method implemented by the listener, which you should not call direct; that's supposed to be called by the scanner instance.

Comment: The `case 2` code is extracted from the SDK of the manufacturer to exploit the scanner module on android.* For stack trace I was reading that C++Builder doesn't provide stacktraces and that i should you third party tools ? I'll search more on how to get a real callstack trace asap.

Comment: Not a stack trace.. the callstack. When the error occurs, the Debugger Exception Notification window should appear. Clicking Break usually brings up the callstack window

Comment: Yes of course ^^ it just didn&#39;t hold much info with useless hexadecimal references. And only seemed to go deeper into low level librairies, and calls before dispatchnative were CPU unkown greyed lines.

Comment: Here the callstack, 
`System._DbgExcNotify(-7746616,0xf3ec5d60,0xdecaa6bf,0xf3ec5d60,0xdecaa6bf)
System.NotifyReRaise(0xf3ec5d60,0xdecaa6bf)
System._RaiseAtExcept(0xf3ec5d60,0xdecaa6bf)
System._RaiseExcept(0xf3ec5d60)
Androidapi.Jnibridge.dispatchToNative(0xf4d97c00,0xff89ce4c,0xff89ce50,0xff89ce54,3708638752)
:E164A794 ??
:E164A794 ??`